# Is there anything special about fasting in the day of mid-Sha'ban?

Tags: sunnah, ibadah, sawm, bidah

While I've always known that fasting the day of Mid-Sha'ban is good and special, and tried to do so most times. Recently I've been told that there's nothing special about it!

So to ask, is there anything special about fasting the day of mid-Sha'ban? is it Sunnah or not? please give evidence Hadith (or aya) and show how strong/weak they (Hadiths) are, since I was told all Hadiths about Mid-Shaban are either weak or fabricated (موضوع).

P.S: This question is about the **day** of mid-Sha'ban, for the **night** of mid-Sha'ban, see [this question.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1203/167)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes nothing special about this days and all Hadiths are fabricated (موضوع).

At the [IslamQA They answer that](http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/49675)

> Ibn Baz said
>
> Celebrating the night of the fifteenth of Sha’baan (Laylat al-Nusf min
>   Sha’baan) by praying etc, or singling out this day for fasting, is a
>   reprehensible bid’ah (innovation) according to the majority of
>   scholars, and there is no basis for this in sharee’ah.

And they [answer another question](http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/8907) about that and said

> There is no saheeh marfoo’ report that speaks of the virtue of the
>   middle of Sha’baan that may be followed, not even  in the chapters on
>   al-Fadaa’il (chapters on virtues in books of hadeeth etc.). Some
>   maqtoo’ reports (reports whose isnaads do not go back further than the
>   Taabi’een) have been narrated from some of the Taabi’een, and there
>   are some ahaadeeth, the best of which are mawdoo’ (fabricated) or
>   da’eef jiddan (very weak). These reports became very well known in
>   some countries which were overwhelmed by ignorance; these reports
>   suggest that people’s lifespans are written on that day or that it is
>   decided on that day who is to die in the coming year. On this basis,
>   it is not prescribed to spend this night in prayer or to fast on this
>   day, or to single it out for certain acts of worship. One should not
>   be deceived by the large numbers of ignorant people who do these
>   things. And Allaah knows best.

And about weak ahaadeeth if we must take it or no, The scholars differed concerning acting upon weak ahaadeeth, Some scholar said it's ok to acting upon it with some conditions and some said forbidden that.

You can see this [answer](http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/44877) about it

> Al-Haafiz ibn Hajar (may Allaah have mercy on him) summed up the
>   conditions for weak ahaadeeth
>
> 1 – It should not be very weak, and one should not act upon a hadeeth
>   which was narrated only by one of the liars or those who are accused
>   of lying, or whose mistakes are serious.
>
> 2 – It should mention a good deed for which there is a basis in
>   sharee’ah.
>
> 3 – When acting upon it one should not believe that the action is
>   well-founded, rather he should do it on the basis of erring on the
>   side of caution.

And what i know you concerning acting upon weak ahaadeeth after condition above, Weak ahaadeeth must not conflicts with ahaadeeth Saheha you must do what ahaadeeth Saheha said.

God bless you

Answer (score 1):

The people who claim that *having fast in the day of mid-Sha'ban is valuable* depend on their this claim for the reason that they think the night of that day is special. **They have no any other reason.** Since [that question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1207/4) explains that their this assumption was wrong, and that day didn't have any specialty at all, the hadiths about his matter were weak, then we understand that having fast in that day has no *extra* benefit. If you have fast that day, your fast becomes a normal fast; it wouldn't give you any bonus [sawab](http://www.islamic-dictionary.com/index.php?word=thawab)s.