# What is Shab E Barat and what is its reality in Islam?

Tags: sunnah, reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Special worship on the night of mid-Sha'ban](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/special-worship-on-the-night-of-mid-shaban)

What is the significance of Shab-e-barat in Qur’an and Hadith?

People of our town cook sweet dishes on the night of 15th Shaban. Some say, that the fates are written and scaled on this night. It is also said that Allah (SWT) forgives all the sins in this night.

Please explain the true significance with true quotes of Quran Kareem and Ahadees.

Comment: Yes that question and answer served my purpose.